# Wordpress query to find posts with exactly sentence from search input

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, search

I am a beginner front-end developer, and these are my first steps with Wordpress.

How can I show posts which have the search term from the search input in their title or in their content? I don't want to use plugins or the built-in Wordpress searching with its reload page.

This is my code:

HTML

```
<form class="search__form" action="" method="POST">
  <div class="search__input-container">
    <input type="text" name="search" class="search__input search__input-js" placeholder="Search">
  </div>
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
$('.search__input-js').on('change', function(){
    var search = $('.search__input').val();
    search = search.toLowerCase();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: ajax_options.admin_ajax_url,
      data:{

          search: search,
          action: 'ajax_func'
      },

      success: function(result) {
        $('.return-msg').html('');
        $('.return-msg').html(result);
      },
      error: function(e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    });
  });
```

Functions.php

```
function ajax_func() {
  wp_reset_postdata();
  $search_term = '';
  $result = '';

  if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $search_term .= $_POST['search'];
  }else{
    $search_term = '';
  }

  $args= array(
    'post_type' => array('post', 'case-study'),

'HERE' 

  );

  $the_query_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
  if ( $the_query_posts->have_posts() ) {
      while ( $the_query_posts->have_posts() )  {
          $the_query_posts->the_post();


          $result .='
          <div class="col-lg-4">';
          $result .='
            <a class="post__link" href="'.get_the_permalink().'">
              <div class="post__container">';

                if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
                  $result .= '

                    '.get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), 'post-thumbnail', ['class' => 'post__img', 'alt' => get_the_title()]).'
                  ';
                } else {
                  $result .= '
                    <img class="img-responsive responsive--full post__img" src="" />
                ';
                }
                $result .='
                  <div class="post__background">
                    <p class="post__category">'.get_the_category(get_the_ID())[0]->name .'</p>';
                    $result .='<p class="post__name">'.get_the_title().'</p>';
                    $result .='<div class="post__desc">'.get_field('post_short_desc').'</div>';
                    $result .='
                  </div>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>';

    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    } else {
      $result .= '<div class="col-12">0 posts</div>';
      wp_reset_postdata();
    }
    echo $result;
    die();

} 
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'cc_post_title_filter', 10, 2 );
  add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_func', 'ajax_func');
  add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_func', 'ajax_func');
```

Ajax works correctly, and I know that I should write some function and set up a special WP query to find my posts where I write 'HERE', but I don't know how. Could anybody give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

[WP_Query has a search parameter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Search_Parameter) you can pass into it. It's also built in should you not want to use AJAX ( example.com/?s=query+here ). Altogether it would look like this:

```
$args= array(
    'post_type' => array( 'post', 'case-study' ),
    's' => $search_term
);
```

Answer (score -1):

It's an old topic, I know, but if you are looking for a solution, in doc, in [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#search-parameters) class you can see the `s` parameter, but there's `sentence` parameter also, even though it doesn't appear in the doc.

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => array( 'post', 'case-study' ),
        'sentence'  => true,
        's'         => $search_term
    );
```